# Pandas rolling mean not working properly

Tags: programming, rolling

I have the following dataframe `df` on which I want to compute a `4`-window moving average :

```
2000-01-03     NaN
2000-01-04     NaN
2000-01-05    -5.0
2000-01-06    1.40
2000-01-07    0.47
```

I want the following output:

```
2000-01-03     NaN
2000-01-04     NaN
2000-01-05     NaN
2000-01-06    -1.8
2000-01-07    -1.04
```

With `df.rolling(4).mean()`, I get

```
2000-01-03     NaN
2000-01-04     NaN
2000-01-05     NaN
2000-01-06     NaN
2000-01-07     NaN
```

By setting the parameter `min_periods=1`, I get

```
2000-01-03     NaN
2000-01-04     NaN
2000-01-05    -5.0
2000-01-06    -1.8
2000-01-07    -1.04
```

How do I get rid of  `NaN`s outside my rolling window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not at all a quantitative finance question and will probable be moved to StackExchange, but in any case...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, np.nan, -5.0, 1.4, 0.47])
df
```

[image]

The NaN values are expected for the first periods, since there are not enough elements to compute the rolling window. To get what you want, you could use:

```
df.rolling(4, min_periods=2).mean()
```

[image]

If you really want to remove the NaN values from you result, you can just do:

```
df.rolling(4, min_periods=2).mean().dropna()
```

[image]

Or:

```
df.rolling(4, min_periods=2).mean().fillna(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this would mean groping for ways to find out the right min_periods parameter for each column, assuming I have an entire whole dataframe...